Difficulty playing non-MP4 video formats in Laravel website
I'm currently working on a Laravel project where I need to display videos on a website. However, some of the videos provided by the client are in non-MP4 formats such as MTS( vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts), AVI. The video player on the website only supports MP4 format. I'm looking for a solution to play these non-MP4 video formats directly on the website without requiring users to download them.
@if(isset($temoignage->videos) && count($temoignage->videos) > 0)
        <h1>Videos</h1>
        @foreach($temoignage->videos as $video)
            <video id="my-video" class="video-js" preload="auto" width="320" height="240" controls data-setup="{}">
                <source src="{{ asset('folder/video/'. $temoignage->title . '/' . $video->name) }}">
                Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la balise vidéo.
                <p class="vjs-no-js">
                    Pour regarder cette vidéo, veuillez activer JavaScript, ou envisagez de mettre à jour votre navigateur à une version qui
                    <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">prend en charge les vidéos HTML5</a>.
                </p>
            </video>
            
            @php
                // Récupérer le nom de fichier et son extension
                $videoName = pathinfo($video->name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $videoExtension = pathinfo($video->name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if ($videoExtension == 'mpeg-tts') {
                    // Supprimer la partie vnd.dlna de $videoName
                    $videoName = str_replace('.vnd.dlna', '', $videoName);

                    // Ajouter .mts à la fin
                    $videoName .= '.mts';
                } else {
                    // Conserver l'extension telle quelle
                    $videoName .= '.' . $videoExtension;
                }

                // Afficher le lien de téléchargement
                echo '<a href="' . asset('folder/video/' . $temoignage->title . '/' .$videoName) . '" class="button is-info is-small is-responsive"> if the player does not work click here to download</a>';

                // Afficher le bouton de suppression
                echo '<span class="modal-open button is-danger is-small is-responsive ' . (auth()->user()->role === 'staff admin' ? ' is-disabled' : '') . '" status-name="Confirm deletion" traget-modal=".delete-modal-video" data_id="' . $video->id . '" data_name="' . $video->name . '" data-url="' . route('deleteVideo', $video->id) . '">delete</span>';
            @endphp
            <hr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No associated video</p>
    @endif

I attempted to display the videos using HTML5 video tags and Laravel's assets feature to link to the video files stored on the server. However, the browser only plays MP4 videos and non-MP4 formats are not supported. instead of opening the video with the url like with mp4 it starts downloading the videos, but the client prefers the videos to be played directly on the website. help me find a solution to play videos directly on the website as with mp4 formats
I tried various approaches before arriving at the current solution. The code I shared above is the only one that worked correctly. I previously attempted other methods, but they failed to display the videos properly, except for MP4 format videos.

most browsers support a subset of all the available video codecs. see http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works for what works.
I suggest you look at using something like ffmpeg on the server to transcode these files, or use a VOD service like api.video to host them for you and handle transcoding

@YakoubFergag MTS holds H264 video (sometimes called AVC) and this can be copied into an MP4 container. The AVI is more generic and could hold any codec. If the AVI and the MTS have H264 video then it might be possible to play them (although with some extra coding). Check one or two AVI with MediaInfoOnline to see what video codec they use. Let us know.

yes I tried an avi video the codec is H264. do you want other information or just the codec?
